# Is import case insensitive in React?

Tags: reactjs, import, react-hooks, case-insensitive

I have been following a React course online. When the course talked about hooks in React, I saw this sample code:

```
import AlertContext from '../../context/alert/alertContext'
```

But when I went to `alertContext.js` module, I noticed the default exported module object is `alertContext`, the object name started with "a" instead of "A". The code is like `export default alertContext`.

Does it mean import is case insensitive?

Comment: It means that default exports are not `named exports`. A default export can be imported as any name what so ever... (that is js valid). Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: Thank you. It helps. I will check out the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a default export on a custom component, you can import it with any name you like.

default export can have any name inside it and can be imported with any other name on other components.

But its important to import the custom component with UpperCase as React understands uppercase as a custom component and lower case as a native component.

Native Components => `<div> , <p>, <input>` etc
Custom Components => `<AlertContext>`

Example:

```
/*customComponent.js*/
const customComponent = () => <div> I am Custom </div>

export default customComponent;

/*App.js*/
import MyCustomComponent from './customComponent'

const App = () => <MyCustomComponent />
export default App;
```